# Displaying element's layer style in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display a div's layer style using javascript. My js code is as follows:

```
<body>
<script>
function displayStyle(objectId,styleName){
    var objRef=document.getElementById(objectId);
    var styleValue=eval(objRef.style + styleName);
    window.alert(styleName +" =" +styleValue);
    }

</script>
<div id="myObject" style="position: absolute; left:50px; top: 200px; background-color: #cccccc;">My Object</div>
<form>
 style:<input type="text" name="styleText">
<input type="button" value="Display Style"
onClick="displayStyle('myObject',this.form.styleText.value);">
</form>
</body>
```

The problem is on the button click, the style property doesnot pop up in window alert.The console shows the
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Plz help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)

```
function displayStyle(objectId, styleName) {
    var objRef = document.getElementById(objectId);
    var styleValue = objRef.style[styleName];
    window.alert(styleName + " =" + styleValue);
}
```

Comment: Plz can you explain why var styleValue = objRef.style[styleName]; and

Comment: you are trying to access a member value of the object `objRef.style` using a dynamic key stored in the variable `styleName`,  for this purpose you can use [Member Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators), since you have a dynamic key the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) is the right choice

Answer (score 0):

I really do not recommend using eval();

The other problem is you are missing a dot in the line.

```
var styleValue = eval(objRef.style + '.' + styleName);
```

But this will only work assuming you are passing a valid style property name through also. I would try using one of the approaches below.

If you want to get to one of the style attributes property values you can simple use.

```
   function displayStyle(objectId, styleName) {
        var objRef = document.getElementById(objectId),
            styleValue = objRef.style.getPropertyValue(styleName);
       window.alert(styleName +" = " +styleValue);
   }
```

Another way is to use the square bracket syntax.
In JS you can access the inner properties in an Object with a . like most C based languages. But they also give you a string based accessor.

```
var person = {
    name: 'Rick'
}

console.log(person.name); //Rick
console.log(person['name']); //Rick
```

This system works on any object in JS.
However using this on a Style object may result in different property names being used.

E.G in HTML style attributes you use margin-left. If you want this value using the square brackets you have to use style['marginLeft'];

If want to get all the style properties that have been rendered on the object you can also use.

```
window.getComputedStyle(objRef);
```

Which returns you an object of style properties, but with calculated heights etc. But it does not work in older browsers.

Sorry if this is not clear I typed it out on my phone.